# curve fitting through a specific point in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

If I have data points x and y, each size of 15 rows and one column, how do I force the linear curve fit to go through a point, for example (x=1, y=15)?

Thank you,

Edit to include my data points.

x = [5.998,6.477,6.477,6.477,8.789,11.480,12,12,13.53,17.65,18.16,19.91,23.48,25.42,31.17];
y = [17.5,26.9,24.87,63.38,26.5,32.21,30.34,84.6,41.24,52.91,79.77,47.31,76.81,51.8,57.85];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, equation is `y = kx+n => n = 15-k` in your case.

```
fit(..., @(k,x)(k*x+15-k))
```

If you want more general constraints (say the n-th order polynomial should pass through points A, B, C), you should look at https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94272-how-do-i-constrain-a-fitted-curve-through-specific-points-like-the-origin-in-matlab

Comment: Thank you for the reply, That example yields only a horizontal line passing through (1,15).  `fit(x,y, (k*x+15-k))` gives me `First input argument must be a string or cell array. Error in ==> fit at 148 model = fittype( fittypeobj );` error.

Comment: @B.Z. Huh, it works fine for me with your x and y. `f = fit(x', y', @(k,x)(k*x+15-k)); plot(x, y); hold on; plot(f)`

Comment: Thank you, I was using R2009a Matlab. Changed to 2016 and it works.